# How do I create additional logins or admins for Azure SQL using a bicep?

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-sql-database, azure-bicep

I am creating an Azure SQL database using infrastructure as code.

I create the server and set the administrator as the Azure AD group our DBAs are in. Then I create a database on this server.

Everything is created without errors, but I can't connect to this database because I am not in that AD group.

I need to create a new user with rights to the database (but maybe not the server), but I don't see a way to do it.

Usually, in SSMS, I would create a login and associate that login with a user.

1. I can't do this because I don't have a way to log in.
2. I don't want to do this because it's manual.

Is there a way to make two administrators?
Our DBA team has to be administrators, but perhaps I could also be an admin on this server.

Even if I was an admin, how do I create accounts for other developers and our applications? I want to do it with an IaC approach, preferably with the bicep.

If I have to create the accounts with a SQL script, I need an account for the script to connect as.

Comment: In Azure SQL Database each database is a contained database, therefore you create the `USER`s directly in the database and specify the authentication method there. The `USER`s don't need a related `LOGIN`.

Comment: How do I create them?
There is no option to create a user in the bicep. Am I missing something?
I can't login to the database because I don't have an account.

Comment: @DonChambers Can you tell me how did you create a sql server with ad group as admin? Failing in my case with invalid login

Answer (score 1):

> I need to create a new user with rights to the database (but maybe not the server), but I don't see a way to do it.

**AFAIK, you cannot add more than one Azure Active Directory admin to Azure Sql.**

[image]

**The resolution can be:**

1. Add yourself as a member in the group of Azure AD your DBAs. After this deploy SQL database using bicep with Azure Active Directory admin as that group.
2. Deploy SQL database using bicep with Azure Active Directory admin as DBA's group. After this login with one of the member of that DBA's group and create a user for Azure AD user on your database. and give him appropriate role.

```sql
CREATE  USER [bob@contoso.com] FROM  EXTERNAL PROVIDER;
```

SQL server logged in with member of DBA's group which is added in Azure Active Directory admin as group.

[image]

SQL server logged in with another AD user after creating his contained user with above query.

[image]

Comment: Do you have example bicep/powershell/sql that does all this?